# Supplying my own configuration to replace EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration in spring-boot-actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm currently working trying replace the HealthMvcEndpoint bean with one that adds another request mapping to accept a parameter. In order to do that I have subclassed HealthMvcEndpoint and added the request mapping like so:

```java
public class MyHealthMvcEndpoint extends HealthMvcEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, params={"param"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Object invoke(Principal principal,  @RequestParam(value="param") String param) {

        // do something with param
        return super.invoke(principal);
}
```

In order to use my newly defined healthMvcEndpoint, I have subclassed EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration and replaced the previous bean definition with and instance of MyHealthMvcEndpoint.

```java
@ManagementContextConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ HealthMvcEndpointProperties.class, EndpointCorsProperties.class })
public class MyEndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration extends EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private HealthMvcEndpointProperties healthMvcEndpointProperties;

    @Autowired
    private ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties;

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnBean(HealthEndpoint.class)
    @ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint("health")
    public HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint(HealthEndpoint delegate) {
        ManagementServerProperties.Security security = this.managementServerProperties.getSecurity();
        boolean secure = (security != null && security.isEnabled());
        HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint = new MyHealthMvcEndpoint(delegate, secure);
        // HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint = new HealthMvcEndpoint(delegate, secure);
        if (this.healthMvcEndpointProperties.getMapping() != null) {
            healthMvcEndpoint
                .addStatusMapping(this.healthMvcEndpointProperties.getMapping());
        }
        return healthMvcEndpoint;
    }

}
```

I would expect for spring-boot to autoconfigure the beans in the same order as before the replacement by simply autoconfiguring the contents of MyEndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration instead but it seems to change bean creation order and causes the following error:'

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at Application.main(Application.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 23 more
```

Which is stange since I'm not using jdbc in my application so I looked into what beans are being created and I found that when I do the above configuration, MyEndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration is configured much earlier than EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration is normally and dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor is created when it is not being configured normally.

I've tried @ConfigureAfter to attempt to change the order of bean creation but no luck. If anyone can explain, it would be greatly appreciated.